# How Can I convert a tilde separated csv file into xml in java

Tags: java, csv

```
1RW~800~4~22~1~48:2~true
1RW~800~16~39~1~48:2~true
1RW~800~640~330~1~48:2~true
1RW~800~40~124~1~48:2~true
```

this is my csv file text and i want to read this and put each value in a row separated by ~ into different xml element . I will loop through this and form 4 different xmls

Comment: What is the desired XML format?

Comment: What XML element are you trying to put this into?

Comment: <Data1>
<Value1>1RW</Value1>
<Value2>800</Value2><Value3>4</Value3><Value4>22</Value4><Value5>1</Value5><Value6>48:2</Value6></Data1><Data2>.....</Data2>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) (short tutorial [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/)) to read your CSV file and [write it to a XML](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/).

Here is one way this could be done using the mentioned technologies

```
// create the CSVReader
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), '~');

// create the DocumentBuilder which will create our xml documents
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

// create the transoformer which will make the xml ready for storing
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

// loop through the 4 rows
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    // read one row from the csv
    String [] line = reader.readNext()

    // create an xml document
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("data-"+i);
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    // iterate over the entries in the row
    for (String s : line) {
        Element element = doc.createElement("element");
        element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(s));
        rootElement.appendChild(element);
    }

    // finally save it:
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("file_"+i+".xml"));
    transformer.transform(source, result);

    System.out.println("File " + i + " saved!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I will try this and will let you know if that worked

Comment: i hope it compiles. i wrote this on in the SO editor so tell me if i messed anything up ;)

Comment: :) surely . But I am sure you written it perfectly

Comment: i already found an error. Change `Element element = doc.createTextNode("element");` to `Element element = doc.createElement("element");`